# XAMARIN PCL consumming WCF

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin.ios, cross-platform

I'm developping in Xamarin PCL a project cross-platform I'm testing on IOS and android with Visual studio 2015 V4.6. I need to include System.ServiceModel In my portable Class to consume WCF Services. I can't Include it with Nuget Packets.

```
Could not install package 'System.ServiceModel.Primitives 4.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I tried to include directly **Right clic on References -> [path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN5Og.png)->System.ServiceModel[4.0.0.0] and then add***
I have this error message

```
  ' Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Can not resolve reference: /Users/ludovic/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/DemoHandyLife.iOS/725fe7b4d3cb829a82e1002d425b8f86/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll DemoHandyLife.iOS   C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets 696'
```

If I add System.ServiceModel[5.0.0.0] I have these Error Message

```
Error   CS0012  The type 'CookieContainer' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Net, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.  


Error   CS0012  The type 'CookieContainer' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Net, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
```

I tried to add the system.Net Version=5.0.5.0 automatically but nothing happen.
Can someone Help me? Thanks in advance

Tell me if you need more details.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can't directly add your WCf service to your Portable class library, I suggest to convert your wcf Service in a wcf rest Service. I let you watch the tutorial

or you can follow this tutorial if you absolutely want wsdl service. you can add it directly in your pcl class with the last xamarin version 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/